# Ошибка компиляции оператора ? :

Tags: c#, компиляция

Этот код приводит к ошибке компиляции:

```
InputActionMap currentActionMap
= Menu.ESC_Controller.IS_PAUSED
? myDroneInputController.myPlayerInputData.MenuControls
: myDroneInputController.myPlayerInputData.PlayerControls;
```

Структуры и класс прописаны так:

```
public partial class @PlayerInputData : IInputActionCollection2, IDisposable {
...
     public struct PlayerControlsActions { }
     public PlayerControlsActions @PlayerControls => new 
     PlayerControlsActions(this);
...
     public struct MenuControlsActions { }
     public MenuControlsActions @MenuControls => new MenuControlsActions(this);
...
} 


public sealed class InputActionMap : ICloneable, ISerializationCallbackReceiver, IInputActionCollection2, IInputActionCollection, IEnumerable<InputAction>, IEnumerable, IDisposable
{....
}

// MenuControls 
public struct MenuControlsActions
{
        private @PlayerInputData m_Wrapper;
        public MenuControlsActions(@PlayerInputData wrapper) { m_Wrapper = wrapper; }
        public InputAction @ESC_MenuESC => m_Wrapper.m_MenuControls_ESC_MenuESC;
}

// PlayerControls:
 public struct PlayerControlsActions
{
        private @PlayerInputData m_Wrapper;
        public PlayerControlsActions(@PlayerInputData wrapper) { m_Wrapper = wrapper; }
        public InputAction @ESC => m_Wrapper.m_PlayerControls_ESC;
}
```

Ошибка выглядит так:

> Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is
> no implicit conversion between 'PlayerInputData.MenuControlsActions'
> and 'PlayerInputData.PlayerControlsActions'

VS говорит:

> Feature 'target-typed conditional expression' is not available in C#
> 8.0. Please use language version 9.0 or greater

1. Обьясните пожалуйста как version 9.0 будет преобразовывать объект типа struct в class?
2. Почему оператор ? : здесь не работает, а if()-else работает?

Comment: добавь пример if-else который работает. Из приведенного кода непонятно как InputActionMap  связан с PlayerControlsActions или MenuControlsActions

Comment: Вроде этот код не помогает пониманию, но вдруг:
public partial class @ PlayerInputData : IInputActionCollection2, IDisposable
{
...
    public struct PlayerControlsActions
    { }
    public PlayerControlsActions @ PlayerControls => new PlayerControlsActions(this);
...
    public struct MenuControlsActions
    { }
    public MenuControlsActions @ MenuControls => new MenuControlsActions(this);
...
}
===
InputActionMap описан так:
public sealed class InputActionMap : ICloneable, ISerializationCallbackReceiver, IInputActionCollection2, IInputActionCollection {...}

Comment: добавь его прямо в вопрос

Comment: `оператор ? : не работает` - в старых версиях языка, он требовал одинаковых типов что для `true`, что для `false`, вы не можете задать в условии два разных типа и ожидать один конкретный на выходе. Начиная с 9 версии языка, его прокачали, он теперь сам понимает, что от него хотят. Допустим класс `Car`, от него наследуются 2 класса `Lada` и `BMW`, вы пишете `Car = lada ?? bmw`, все, с#9 позволит вам это сделать, он сам нужный объект приведет к нужному типу, хотя классы, по сути, разные. А в старых версиях надо было писать, например так: `Car = (Car)lada ?? (Car)bmw`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, `??` И `?:` - это ж разные операторы, в принципе никак не связанные между собой

Comment: @Grundy То, что я написал выше, относится как к `?:`, так и к `??`. Они по сути одинаковые, только `?:` позволяет задать конкретное условие, а `??` это проверка левого на null, если оно таким и является, то возвращается правое значение, но опять же, c# 9 позволяет указать разные типы и приравнять их к одному конкретному.